# Defining a Mutation argument in graphql-yoga

Tags: node.js, graphql

How do I create a Mutation with arguments for a resolver defined in `graphql-yoga` as:

```
const resolvers =
  Mutation: {
    createProject(root, args) {
      const id = (Number(last(data.projects).id) + 1).toString()
      const newProject = { ...args, id: id }
      ...
```

I've tried the following:

```
mutation CreateProject($name: String!) {
  createProject {
    data: {
      name: $name
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
mutation CreateProject($name: String!) {
  createProject($name: name) {
    statusCode
  }
}
```

which produces

[image]

and various other structures unsuccessfully.

There seems to be no reference to a Mutation in either the project README or any of the three examples.

**Update**

I'm now using:

```
mutation CreateProject($name: String!) {
  createProject(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

which is so similar to examples I've seen on the net that I feel it must be valid & the syntax is not rejected.

The schema definition is:

```
  scalar ID

  type Project {
    id: ID
    type: ProjectType
    name: String
  }

  interface MutationResult {
    statusCode: Int
    message: String
  }

  type ProjectMutationResult implements MutationResult {
    statusCode: Int
    message: String
    project: Project
  }

  type Mutation {
    createProject: ProjectMutationResult
  }
```

However on submitting the mutation, I receive:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Unknown argument \"name\" on field \"createProject\" of type \"Mutation\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 2,
            "column": 17
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"id\" on type \"ProjectMutationResult\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 3,
            "column": 5
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "message": "Cannot query field \"name\" on type \"ProjectMutationResult\".",
        "locations": [
          {
            "line": 4,
            "column": 5
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you're seeing an error, please include that in your question. This is not only helpful in resolving your issue, but also helps others find your question when doing a search.

Comment: The graphical page is not letting me submit the query due to syntax errors. I'll see if I can capture the tooltip it produces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your type definition:

1. The `createProject` mutation does not expect any argument:

```
type Mutation {
  createProject: ProjectMutationResult
}
```

2. The `ProjectMutationResult` type does not have an `id` field nor a `name` field:

```
type ProjectMutationResult implements MutationResult {
  statusCode: Int
  message: String
  project: Project
}
```

So when you run the mutation:

```
mutation CreateProject($name: String!) {
  createProject(name: $name) {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

you have a complete discrepancy between what you're feeding your GraphQL server and what it's actually expecting.

So first of all, if you want to be able to set a `name` to your project when you create it, you need to amend your `createProject` definition to this:

```
type Mutation {
  createProject(name: String!): ProjectMutationResult
}
```

(if you want the naming to be optional, set name to be of type `String` rather than `String!`)

Then, assuming you want to retrieve the newly created project id and name from your mutation, change the mutation itself to:

```
mutation CreateProject($name: String!) {
  createProject(name: $name) {
    project {
      id
      name
    }
  }
}
```

You need to do this because your `createProject` mutation returns a `ProjectMutationResult` which itself contains a `project` field of type `Project`, which is the one defining the `id` and `name` fields.